# Why are there inconsistencies between the usage of unmanagedJars and libraryDependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

SBT 0.13.8

I'm trying to puzzle out what seems like inconsistent behavior between `unmanagedJars` and `libraryDependencies`. I did my best to attempt to summarize my confusion in the `Build.scala` file below.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object DemoBuild extends Build {
  def findTypesafeConfigJar(baseDir:File) =
    Attributed.blank(baseDir / "extra-jars/config-1.2.1.jar")

  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    //CONTROL
    //typesafeConfigAsLibraryDependency()
    //ATTEMPT #1
    //typesafeConfigAsUnmanagedJar1()
    //ATTEMPT #2
    //typesafeConfigAsUnmanagedJar2()
  )

  val root = (project in file(".")).settings(
    //ATTEMPT #3
    //typesafeConfigAsUnmanagedJar1()
    //ATTEMPT #4
    //typesafeConfigAsUnmanagedJar2()
  )

  def typesafeConfigAsLibraryDependency() =
    libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"

  def typesafeConfigAsUnmanagedJar1() =
    unmanagedJars += findTypesafeConfigJar(baseDirectory.value)

  def typesafeConfigAsUnmanagedJar2() =
    unmanagedJars in Compile += findTypesafeConfigJar(baseDirectory.value)
}
```

---

Attempt #1 failed:

```
[error] Reference to undefined setting: 
[error] 
[error]   {.}/*:unmanagedJars from {.}/*:unmanagedJars (/somewhere/on/filesystem/_root/project/DemoBuild.scala:28)
[error]      Did you mean compile:unmanagedJars ?
```

---

Attempt #2 failed:

```
[error] Reference to undefined setting: 
[error] 
[error]   {.}/compile:unmanagedJars from {.}/compile:unmanagedJars (/somewhere/on/filesystem/_root/project/DemoBuild.scala:31)
[error]      Did you mean compile:unmanagedJars ?
```

---

Attempt #3 failed:

```
[error] Reference to undefined setting: 
[error] 
[error]   *:unmanagedJars from *:unmanagedJars (/somewhere/on/filesystem/_root/project/DemoBuild.scala:28)
[error]      Did you mean compile:unmanagedJars ?
```

---

Attempt #4 succeeded...

I've been trying to leverage the material in the [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html) section of the SBT tutorial to no avail. The only thing I understand is that reducing the scope of `unmanagedJars` to the `Compile` configuration of the root project makes the monsters go away. However, I have no idea why that is.

1. Whatever happened to [delegation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html#Delegation)?
2. How come the `libraryDependencies` setting is so radically different and so much easier to use?
3. The `(project in file(".")).settings(...)` mantra is just way too magical for my liking, is there a 'cleaner' alternative? I tried adding different things (along the lines of `unmanagedJars in (RootProject, Compile)`) to the `override lazy val settings` block without any success.
4. Are there any *runnable* examples which showcase scoping along different axis (especially with `unmanagedJars`)?
5. What's the difference between `unmanagedJars` and `unmanagedClasspath` settings?

One final note, I'm not interested in using the `*.sbt` build definitions, so please keep the answers specific to `*.scala` build definitions.